# Can't send post request from code while curl command is working

Tags: c#, json, rest, webforms, binance

I am trying to place order on Binance.

Did everything according to documentation [LINK TO DOCUMENTATION](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security)

Code :

```
public void PlaceOrder(string baseCurrency, string quoteCurrency, OrderType orderType, decimal quantity, decimal price, OrderSubType orderSubType)
    {
        string timestamp = GetTimestamp().ToString();
        string assetPair = baseCurrency.ToUpper() + quoteCurrency.ToUpper();

        string orderSubTypeId = "";
        if (orderSubType == OrderSubType.LimitOrder)
        {
            orderSubTypeId = "LIMIT";
        }
        if (orderSubType == OrderSubType.MarketOrder)
        {
            orderSubTypeId = "MARKET";
        }

        string type = "";
        if (orderType == OrderType.Sell)
        {
            type = "SELL";
        }
        else
        {
            type = "BUY";
        }

        string paramString = String.Format(
            "symbol={0}&side={1}&type={2}&quantity={3}&recvWindow=60000&timestamp={4}",
            assetPair, type, orderSubTypeId, quantity.ToString(), timestamp);

        string signature = Encode(paramString, secretKey);
        string url = string.Format("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?{0}&signature={1}", paramString, signature);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", apiKey);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    }
```

string url is correct. Because, I copy-pasted it into URL and running curl command worked.

CURL :

> curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: API_KEY_GOES_HERE" -X POST
>   "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=ETHUSDT&side=SELL&type=MARKET&quantity=0.10000000&recvWindow=60000&timestamp=1583924648428&signature=SIGNATURE_GOES_HERE(signature is correct, I checked it)"

parameters passed to the method are correct because url string in code is correct. There is something wrong with request itself.

Comment: What response do u get?

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am not getting any errors. The goal of this erquest is to place order on binance. It doesn't do that unless I use curl command and run it manually.

Comment: How do you know that it is not placing the order?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am checking it on binance manually.

Comment: You are creating an object of HttpWebRequest but there is not code which is actually making request. I believe you need to request.GetResponse() to actually make post request to the API and get the response form there

Comment: https://stickler.de/en/information/code-snippets/httpwebrequest-with-post-data